# Can not count fields correctly in a Django view

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following model:

```
class Download(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
download_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to get how many times certain songs have been downloaded in a period of time.

The query I have built is this:

```
res = Download.objects.filter(download_date__range=[date_1, date_2]).annotate(downloads = Count('id')).values('id', 'song', 'downloads')
```

I have tried also counting song but no success. It keeps returning repeated songs with a count of 1.

Comment: What I want to get is something like this: Song 1 (10 downloads), Song 2 (19 downloads) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Download.objects.filter(download_date__range=[date_1, date_2]).values('song').annotate(downloads = Count('id'))
```

Comment: Saved my day. I thought it was necessary to write the annotated field into the values clause. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must change `order_by`. Explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

```
res = Download.objects.filter(download_date__range=[date_1, date_2])\
              .annotate(downloads=Count('song'))\
              .values('downloads', 'song')\
              .order_by()
```